# QtCreator: deploy to multiple linux embedded devices

Tags: qt, deployment, qt-creator, qt5, cross-compiling

I am currently working on QtCreator 3.0.1 targeting Qt 5.2.1 cross-compiled from ARM (TI AM335x).

I’ve setup my “*Qt version*” and “*Kit*” and “*Device*” in QtCreator and everything is fine... I am able to deploy and run (and debug) my application on the embedded device.

Anyway now I’d like to deploy the application on two devices (my development device, addressed `192.168.79.12` and our testbench device addressed `192.168.79.6`). For this reason I created another “*Generic Linux Embedded*” device and I’d like to show it in the “*Build and run kit selector*”: in other words I’d like to have to possibility to select the kit, the build type (debug or release) and the target device from the “Build and run kit selector”.

In the “*Run settings*” of my project I added a new “*Run configuration*” to do that... but the target of the deployment is always my original device (`192.168.79.12`, which is the default device for the selected kit) and I do not know how to select the second device (`192.168.79.6`) in this running configuration. Is it possible?

[image]

At the moment my workaround was to create a second kit (referencing the same Qt version) and then associate with this kit the second device as the default device, but it is not an optimal solution, because this way I compile twice the project for deploying it to both devices… as the project will grow up it will be a waste of time...

Any idea about that?